# How do I prevent that the width of a flexible form that shows dynamic content depending on an input, changes when said dynamic content is shown?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Here´s the main html doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Formulario Prosepección</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row full-height-row">
      <div id="formulario" class="col-5 w-100">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="title">PROSPECCIÓN DE LEADS</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-4 col-form-label" for="DesarrolloInteres">Desarrollo de interés</label>
              <div class="col-8">
                <select name="DesarrolloInteres" id="DesarrolloInteres" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Desarrollos</option>
                  <optgroup label="Guadalajara">
                    <option value="SOHO 5220">SOHO 5220</option>
                    <option value="Livet Ottawa">Livet Ottawa</option>
                    <option value="SOHO Morelos">SOHO Morelos</option>
                    <option value="Coordenada Lafayette">Coordenada Lafayette</option>
                    <option value="Coordenada Central">Coordenada Central</option>
                    <option value="Coordenada Living">Coordenada Living</option>
                    <option value="SOHO Park Apartments">SOHO Park Apartments</option>
                    <option value="Lírica Towers">Lírica Towers</option>
                    <option value="Coordenada Country">Coordenada Country</option>
                    <option value="Villa Dhara">Villa Dhara</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Monterrey">
                    <option value="Coordenada Cumbres">Coordenada Cumbres</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="León">
                    <option value="Meridiano 101">Meridiano 101</option>
                    <option value="Punta Mayor">Punta Mayor</option>
                    <option value="Arbolé Garden">Arbolé Garden</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Tijuana">
                    <option value="Black Eleven">Black Eleven</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Tulum">
                    <option value="Bohemian La Veleta">Bohemian La Veleta</option>
                    <option value="Okün Residences Tulum">Okün Residences Tulum</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup label="Cancún">
                    <option value="Okün Living Cancún">Okün Living Cancún</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="linea"></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-form-label col-6">Conoce la zona</label>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="zona" id="zona" value="Sí" requiered>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="zona">Sí</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="zona" id="zona" value="No" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="zona">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-form-label col-6">Vivir o Invertir</label>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="uso" id="uso" value="Vivir" required>
                <label for="uso" class="form-check-label">Vivir</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="uso" id="uso" value="Invertir" required>
                <label for="uso" class="form-check-label">Invertir</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="habitaciones" class="col-4 col-form-label">Habitaciones</label>
              <div class="col-8">
                <select name="habitaciones" id="habitaciones" class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="entrega" class="col-4 col-form-label">Tiempo de Entrega</label>
              <div class="col-8">
                <select name="entrega" id="entrega" class="form-control">
                  <option value="Inmediato">Inmediato</option>
                  <option value="1 año">1 año</option>
                  <option value="2 años">2 años</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="linea"></div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="presupuesto" class="col-4 col-form-label">Presupuesto</label>
              <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="presupuesto" placeholder="Presupuesto en mdp">
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-form-label col-6">Formato de Pago</label>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="formatoPago" id="formatoPago" value="Crédito" required>
                <label for="formatoPago" class="form-check-label">Crédito</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="formatoPago" id="formatoPago" value="Recurso Propio" required>
                <label for="formatoPago" class="form-check-label">Recurso Propio</label>
              </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-form-label col-6">Cuenta con enganche</label>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="enganche" id="enganche" value="Sí" required>
                <label for="enganche" class="form-check-label">Sí</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-3">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="enganche" id="enganche" value="No" required>
                <label for="enganche" class="form-check-label">No</label>
              </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" id="margen-enganche">
              <label for="cantidadEnganche" class="col-4 col-form-label">Cantidad de Enganche</label>
              <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="cantidadEnganche" placeholder="Cantidad de Enganche en k">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <button class="btn btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copiar</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contenido-dinamico" class="col-7">
        <div class="overflow-hidden">
          <h2>Contenido Dinámico</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here´s the dynamic content base html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>SOHO 5220</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto">
          <img src="/Desarrollos/Soho5220/logo5220.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>
          <strong>Ubicación:</strong> Av. Guadalupe<br>
          <strong>Referencias:</strong> Cerca de<br>
          <strong>Descripción:</strong> 4 torres<br>
          <strong>Amenidades:</strong> Alberca<br>
        </p>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-6"  style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <img src="/Desarrollos/Soho5220/5220.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3733.187100378821!2d-103.42999142526759!3d20.66196570027665!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8428afffbf683483%3A0x707714d43b8d523c!2sSoho%205220!5e0!3m2!1ses!2smx!4v1686324432298!5m2!1ses!2smx" width="100%" height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="eager" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here´s the CSS:

```
/*Formulario*/
.full-height-row {
    height: 100vh;
  }
#presupuesto::placeholder {
  text-align: left!important;
  unicode-bidi: plaintext;
  direction: ltr!important;
}
#cantidadEnganche::placeholder {
  text-align: left!important;
  unicode-bidi: plaintext;
  direction: ltr!important;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Borde sombreado */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Sombra */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Bordes redondeados */
  }
.wrapper .title {
    margin-top: 0px!important;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: left;
    color: #3d642d ;
}

.linea {
    border-top: 1px solid #3d642d;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
  }
.form-group{
    margin-top: 11px!important;
    margin-bottom: 11px!important;
}

.btn {
   margin: auto 10px auto 10px;
   padding: 8px 10px;
   border: 0px;
   background:  #3d642d;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 3px;
   outline: none;
}
  
.wrapper .form .inputfield .btn:hover {
   background: #336a1d;
}

/*Contenido Dinámico*/
.content-info {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-fluid 
.desarrollo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.content-impact {
  padding: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .content-info,
  .content-image {
    flex: auto;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .content-image {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .content-impact {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

Here´s the JS:

```
//Copiar formulario a portapapeles
function copyToClipboard() {
  var inputValues = {
    habitaciones: document.getElementById("habitaciones").value,
    tiempoEntrega: document.getElementById("entrega").value,
    presupuesto: document.getElementById("presupuesto").value,
    cantidadEnganche: document.getElementById("cantidadEnganche").value,
    };

  var opcionesZona = document.getElementsByName("zona");
  var opcionesUso = document.getElementsByName("uso");
  var opcionesPago = document.getElementsByName("formatoPago");
  var opcionesEnganche = document.getElementsByName("enganche");

  var valorSeleccionadoZona;
  var valorSeleccionadoUso;
  var valorSeleccionadoPago;
  var valorSeleccionadoEnganche;

  for (var i = 0; i < opcionesZona.length; i++) {
    if (opcionesZona[i].checked) {
      valorSeleccionadoZona = opcionesZona[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < opcionesUso.length; i++) {
    if (opcionesUso[i].checked) {
      valorSeleccionadoUso = opcionesUso[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < opcionesPago.length; i++) {
    if (opcionesPago[i].checked) {
      valorSeleccionadoPago = opcionesPago[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < opcionesEnganche.length; i++) {
    if (opcionesEnganche[i].checked) {
      valorSeleccionadoEnganche = opcionesEnganche[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  const message = `Conoce la zona: ${valorSeleccionadoZona}\nUso: ${valorSeleccionadoUso}\nNúmero de habitaciones: ${inputValues.habitaciones}\nTiempo de Entrega: ${inputValues.tiempoEntrega}\nPresupuesto: ${inputValues.presupuesto} mdp\nFormato de Pago: ${valorSeleccionadoPago}\nCuenta con el Enganche: ${valorSeleccionadoEnganche}\nCantidad de enganche: ${inputValues.cantidadEnganche} k`;

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(message)
    .then(() => {
      alert("La información ha sido copiada al portapapeles.");
    })
    .catch(() => {
      alert("No se pudo copiar la información al portapapeles.");
    });
}

//Contenido Dinámico 
const selectContent =  document.getElementById("DesarrolloInteres");
const contenidoDinamico = document.querySelector('#contenido-dinamico');

selectContent.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const opcionSeleccionada = selectContent.value;

  if (opcionSeleccionada === 'SOHO 5220') {
    fetch('/Desarrollos/Soho5220/soho5220.html')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(content => {
        contenidoDinamico.innerHTML = content;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al cargar la página: ', error);
      });
  } else if (opcionSeleccionada === 'Livet Ottawa') {
    fetch('/Desarrollos/Livet Ottawa/ottawa.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(content => {
      contenidoDinamico.innerHTML = content;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error al cargar la página: ', error);
    });
  } else if (opcionSeleccionada === 'opcion3') {
    contenidoDinamico.innerHTML = '<p>Contenido de la opción 3</p>';
  }
});
```

The page is mostly formatted through the bootstrap column and row layout, the principal page is divided into two columns, the one with the form and the one with the dynamic content. The form is one size, the intended size until the dynamic content is shown. Any ideas on how can I fix this?